# amazon dynamodb fiter expression return error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

iam created a table in amazon dynamoDB using web console. this is my table structure after adding some data.

### timestamp | userid  |  text

101 | manaf   | haaaai

102 | manaf   | hello

I need to get the data between two res limits.

this is my code in js.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "regionName",
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
var table = "testTable";
var params = {
    TableName: table,
    FilterExpression :['userid = :id','res >= :val1','res <= :val2'],
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {':id' : 'manaf','res':101, 'res':102} 
};

docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err);
   else console.log(data);
});
```

But i got error like this.

```
{ [InvalidParameterType: Expected params.FilterExpression to be a string]
  message: 'Expected params.FilterExpression to be a string',
  code: 'InvalidParameterType',
  time: Thu May 19 2016 17:24:57 GMT+0530 (IST) }
```

How to add multiple filter options in dynamo db scan method?

Answer (score 1):

Your `FilterExpression` is a list. You have to supply  a string and concatenate elements using dynamos operators ( OR, AND ). 
For example:

```
FilterExpression: "x = 1 AND y = 2"
```

From the docs:

> The syntax for FilterExpression is identical to that of
>   ConditionExpression. In addition, FilterExpression uses the same
>   comparators, functions, and logical operators as ConditionExpression.
>   For more informatio

You may also need to replace keys and values  to avoid error "Attribute  is a reserved keyword; " 
See the docs for more details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ExpressionPlaceholders.html

Comment: thanks for u r answer,  now i changed my filter like this "FilterExpression : 'userid = :id AND timestamp > :v2a AND timestamp < :v2b' "    But i got error "  Invalid FilterExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: timestamp "

Comment: is it possible to solve this without changing table key name?